# Create Menu and Sub menu using Struts2

Tags: struts2

how can I create Dynamic menu and sub menus? I am using following code.

https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/MenuTag#Menu_with_Items_and_Submenus

Comment: Do you have some code to implement?

Answer (score 0):

u have to use two Dropdown list in jsp.
if your both list (menu and sub menu) are dependent then u can use also ajax in java

Comment: Thanks, Can u send me ajax example. <table border="20">
<tr>
<s:iterator value="hrMenu">
<td><a href="index1.jsp" name="<s:property value="hrMenu.keySet()"/>"><s:property/></a></td>

</s:iterator>
</tr>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

just one line u will help this. just copy this line in  iterator in first row

```
<s:iterator value="driverattendance" status="r">
         class="rawcolor"><s:property value="%{#r.index+1}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Can u send me ajax example. hrMenu is my Hashmap. it is displaying output like 1=Home 2=About us ... how can separate key and values. Based on keys I have to display submenus.                       <table border="20">
<tr>
<s:iterator value="hrMenu">
<td><a href="#" />"><s:property/></a></td>
</s:iterator>
</tr>
</table>